# Cannot Edit Area of PlaceHolderMain on default.aspx page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to remove a portion of the default.aspx (custom) page with SharePoint Designer 2010. It is an image with text above it that has been placed outside/above of the Left and Right divs of the page. It is not a web part. When I hover over it, the mouse becomes the "No" symbol (circle with a slash through). I have SCA rights.

How is it possible to remove it?!

Comment: Is it part of the master page?

Answer (score 2):

From trying to replicate what you are doing in my environment, it seems the areas that have the no entry sign are the areas that are part of my master page. Therefore to change them areas I would need to modify the master page, not the page layout.

Comment: That's what I am thinking. Let me give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: How do I tell what master page it is using?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It was actually a table row added into the code of the default.aspx page. So, nothing to do with the master page.